# Atom editor - multiselect by line

Tags: multi-select, atom-editor

I am moving from `Sublime` to `Atom`, and can't find a certain hotkey for the life of me.

`Control+D` will still do a multi-select - select the next instance your highlighted text, at which point you will get multiple cursors.

In `Sublime`, if you selected multiple lines and pressed `control+shift+l`, it would then create a cursor on each line, so you could edit each line at once.

I looked through the hotkey lists for `Atom`, and can't find this. But then I probably don't know the right terminology.

Comment: Is `ctrl+left click` not what you need here?

Comment: @AJGregory that's exactly what I need but I want to know if there's a keyboard shortcut for it instead of clicking to get it done, is there any or do I need to download a plugin for it?

Answer (score 3):

For Windows users,
the default keybindings `ctrl + shift + up / down` seems to work.

For Mac users,
add the following custom keybinding code to the
`/user/<yourName>/.atom/keymap.cson` file

```
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# change the keybinding for ADD SELECTION ABOVE / BELOW
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#  'shift-alt-up': 'editor:add-selection-above'
#  'shift-alt-down': 'editor:add-selection`-below'
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Then place the cursor where you want to start and press and hold `shift + alt` and press `up` or `down` repeatedly to extend the cursor to as many lines as needed.

Comment: little correction - remove ` typo right before -below in this line 'shift-alt-down': 'editor:add-selection`-below'. Otherwise if ppl copy paste your code their "down" arrow will not work. Thanks!

Comment: This didn't work for me, but @Shiv Kumar Baghel's answer (multi-cursor package) worked a treat.  Especially for those forced to use VSCode at work, then get to come home and relax into freedom.

Answer (score 2):

I recently apm'd this package, though I'm not sure if there's a hotkey: https://atom.io/packages/sublime-style-column-selection

Answer (score 2):

The command in the menu `Selection —> Split into Lines` should do what you want. On the Mac the keyboard shortcut is `cmd-shift-l`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [multi-cursor package](https://atom.io/packages/multi-cursor).

Use CTRL/COMMAND to select multiple places.

Comment: Is there no way to select multiple places using the mouse? ctrl + click didn't work for me even with this package

Answer (score 0):

### Adding Key-Binding to `Selection` --> `Split into Lines`

To add the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> Key-binding to this you need to edit your custom keymap file.

1. `Edit` --> `Keymap...` *:opens keymap.cson file*
2. You can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to open a Key Binding Resolver to view currently assigned Key-Bindings to check if the desired key-binding is already occupied.
3. To **re**-map a currently occupied binding simply redifine it in the custom keymap file.

- in my case ***grammar-selector:show*** needed remapping, (remapping to ctrl-shift-j in this case)

Append to : *keymap.cson*

```
  ".platform-darwin atom-text-editor":
    "ctrl-shift-j": "grammar-selector:show"
  ".platform-win32 atom-text-editor":
    "ctrl-shift-j": "grammar-selector:show"
  ".platform-linux atom-text-editor":
    "ctrl-shift-j": "grammar-selector:show"
```

4. Now we add the desired keybinding *(as defined in the [multi-cursor package description](https://atom.io/packages/multi-cursor))*

Append to : *keymap.cson*

```
  '.platform-darwin atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
    'ctrl-shift-l': 'editor:split-selections-into-lines'
  '.platform-win32 atom-text-editor:not([mini])': 
    'ctrl-shift-l': 'editor:split-selections-into-lines'
  '.platform-linux atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
    'ctrl-shift-l': 'editor:split-selections-into-lines'
```

5. Save *keymap.cson* and Restart Atom.

*Note: I have only tested this on linux.*
*Note2: on *mac* , i.e. `darwin` this may not be needed*